# Resizable div just isn't working no matter what I do

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've been trying to use JqueryUIs resizable to create resizable divs like on jsfiddle for example. Jsfiddle makes use of JqueryUI resizable with handles so that you can expand the code editor or the output area displaying the dhtml results (a design etc). I've just about tried every solution given to others who experience problems working with jquery ui's resizble. Is there a way to create a resizable div with CSS only and have a custom handle? I've tried this as well and it's not working either http://blog.softlayer.com/2012/no-iframes-dynamically-resize-divs-with-jquery/ but it's what I'm looking for; two divs, one containing the main content and the other containing sidebar stuff. I made a fiddle quickly of that solution given here: http://jsfiddle.net/asx4M/1/ I would appreciate it if someone could tell me what it is I'm doing wrong or provide me with another solution for what I'm trying to do.

here's the code as well:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            #sidebar {
                width: 49%;
            }
            #content {
                width: 49%;
                float: left;
            }
        </style>

        <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-    ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js">        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $( "#sidebar" ).resizable({      
                });
                $("#sidebar").bind("resize", function (event, ui) {
                    var setWidth = $("#sidebar").width();
                    $('#content').width(1224-setWidth);
                    $('.menu').width(setWidth-6);
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <div id="sidebar"> 
        <div class="sidebar-menu">
            <!-- all your sidebar/navigational items go here -->
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="content">
        <!-- all your main content goes here -->
    </div>
```

Comment: Your question contradicts itself. First you ask us whether it's possible to create a resizable widget with CSS only and then you show us the code that makes use of jQuery UI's Resizable plugin. Make a JSFiddle with your example please.

Comment: I did make a JSFiddle with my example. Please read again.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#content).width(1224-setWidth);
$('.menu).width(setWidth-6);
```

Should be

```
$('#content').width(1224-setWidth);
$('.menu').width(setWidth-6);
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out however I'm still having difficulty with it. Please see the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/asx4M/

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the quotes that you have not closed. for `menu` class and `content` id

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $( "#sidebar" ).resizable({      
    });
    $("#sidebar ").bind("resize", function (event, ui) {
        var setWidth = $("#sidebar").width();
        $('#content').width(1224-setWidth);
        $('.sidebar-menu').width(setWidth-6);
    });
});
```

Comment: You do not have a menu class in the html code you have posted on jsfiddle.

Comment: I've updated the jsfiddle and have closed the quotes and it still does not work so I have not received a good answer yet.

Comment: I've edited the answer to include .sidebar-menu. Hope this is what you are referring to as .menu

Comment: I tried adding .sidebar-menu and still have no luck :( What could be the issue?